# recyclerview inside nested scroll view is not scolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a `recyclerview` inside a `nestedScrollView` and I have stopped the scrolling of `recyclerview` to allow `nestedScrollView` to scroll all the page, but the `nestedScrollView` is not working.

I have set the `nestedScrollingEnabled` of the `recyclerview` to `false`

I have tried to add a hidden view under the `recyclerview` but it has shown on top of the bottom items of `recyclerview`

My layout xml file code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.accad.accadgame.viewmodels.profile.ProfileViewModel" />
</data>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_dim"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_xxdim"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_dim"
            android:src="@drawable/profile"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,1:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_name"
            style="@style/HeadlineTextViewActiveStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_dim"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_dim"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_dim"
            android:text="@{viewModel.profileName}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/circleImageView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/circleImageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/circleImageView"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/profile_details_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_xxdim"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_dim"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/default_dim"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:focusable="false"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/profile_name"
            />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries, I've found the solution

which is to change the `recyclerView`'s height to be `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent` or `0dp` so the `recyclerView` would be like this:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/profile_details_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_xxdim"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_dim"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/default_dim"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:focusable="false"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/profile_name"
        />
```

Answer (score -1):

**Put your static content as the first item in the RV.**

I know this might sound bad but trust me, it's so much better than having a nested RecyclerView.

This will fix recycling, scrolling, dragging and so many other issues with nested RV.